# How to take some data from an object?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-redux

I have to put data from json file to my reducer.
And after mapping this file I got an object which includes data that I need.

```
export const datas = data.properties.map(data => (<store key={Math.floor(Math.random()*1234)} author={data.value} comment={data.group} rate={data.type} />));
```

[this is console log, I just need props from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq9TE.png)

How to get just normall react-table, not an object which is not accepting by reducer state?
Or how to implement it to reducer state to get effect that I need?
I am sorry for stupid questions, I hope you will help me :)

Comment: I'm happy to help but I really do not understand your question at all.  Can you edit your post to include the whole component?

Comment: What you are seeing in your console.log is an `array` of `store` elements.  The `props` are the props that you passed to each `<store/>`: `author`, `comment`, and `rate`.

Comment: Is this what you want? `export const datas = data.properties.map(data =>({author: data.value, comment: data.group, rate: data.type}));`

Comment: Yes! Thank you a lot, i am really gratefull, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

The code which you posted takes an array of objects from a variable `data.properties` and maps them to an array of JSX elements created by the component `store`.  Perhaps it is better readable with line breaks.

```
export const datas = data.properties.map(
    data => (
        <store
            key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1234)}
            author={data.value}
            comment={data.group}
            rate={data.type}
        />
    )
);
```

Your `console.log` of `datas` shows that array of React JSX element instances.  In your array you have 5 objects which are each a JSX element (`$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)`) with `type: "store"` (the component type), the numeric `key` that you created for this element, and a `props` object which contains all of the props that you passed: `author`, `comment`, and `rate` (`key` is a [special prop](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html) so it is not included here).

You are asking to just create an `object` with the props rather than creating a `store` element.  We want to take the array `data.properties` and use the [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to map it to this props object.

The variable name that you use inside of your `.map()` callback can be anything, but as a best practice I recommend that you should not use the variable name `data` again.  Reusing a name is called [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and it won't cause errors, but it can make your code very confusing.  I will call it `datum` instead.

Here is the code that you want:

```
export const propsArray = data.properties.map(
    datum => ({
        key: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1234),
        author: datum.value,
        comment: datum.group,
        rate: datum.type,
    })
);
```